# how to handle mutation error on apollo client?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm trying to solve how handle throwed apollo-server mutation error on apollo client side.

This is my simplified implementation of mutation (createCustomer):

```
  Mutation: {
    createCustomer: async (_, { photoFile, customer }) => {
      const rootPath = path.resolve("./public");
      const customerPath = path.join(rootPath, "/photos/customers");
      try {
        const {
          dataValues: { customerID, firstname, lastname, email, phone }
        } = await models.Customer.create(customer);
        const customerUniqueDir = path.join(customerPath, 
         `${customerID}`);
       } catch (createCustomerError) {
       // throw new apollo-server error
        throw new UserInputError();
      }
    }
}
```

on client side I get following error: 
(first not red error is just console.log in catch block on client)

This error is thrown by apollo-link:

[image]

here is the response from server:

[image]

Here is the implementation of apollo-client:

```
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";
import { ErrorLink } from "apollo-link-error";
import { withClientState } from "apollo-link-state";
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import App from "./App";


const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  addTypename: false
});

const stateLink = withClientState({
  cache,
  resolvers: {
    Mutation: {}
  },
  defaults: {
    customers: { customers: [], count: 0 }
  }
});
const uploadLink = createUploadLink({ uri: "http://localhost:8000/graphql" });
const errorLink = new ErrorLink();

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([stateLink, errorLink, uploadLink]),
  cache,
  connectToDevTools: true
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Is there any solution how could I handle mutation error on client ?

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

The error appeared in apollo-link. So I looked into my implementation of graphql-client and I realized that I forgot to use apollo-link-http module.

So I added following lines of code:

```
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: "http://localhost:8000/graphql" });

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([stateLink,errorLink, httpLink, uploadLink]),
  cache,
  connectToDevTools: true
});
```